# How do you dynamically create a multi-form wizard in Django from the same form?

Tags: python, django, wizard

I am a new user of Django and looking for help in dynamically creating a wizard with the same form. An idea that come to mind is to create a method in the view which returns a list of forms and then pass this list in the url call, is this possible to do? If it is, I am looking for sample code to help me prototype this idea.

Comment: can explain it a little better, what exactly does it mean: "dynamically creating wizard with the same form"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to do this in the exact way you describe, but the [django-formtools](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) docs have a tutorial describing how to implement this use case.